# How to extract a section of text when a character is encounters n times with regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

**Hello I would like to know how can I extract a section of a text when a number of character match n times with REGEX EXPRESSIONS in python.**

For example:

text = **'a123a214a423a87a'**

I want to extract a part of text when 'a' match 4 times

Output will be **'a123a214a423a'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `(a.*?){4}` should match four "a" characters and anything inbetween (except a newline)

```
import re

text = 'a123a214a423a87a'
match = re.search(r'(a.*?){4}', text)
if match:
    print(match.group(0)) # 'a123a214a423a'
```